# Integral of $\frac{e^{-(\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{y})^2}}{\sqrt{1+\overrightarrow{x}^2}\sqrt{1+\overrightarrow{y}^2}}$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{e^{-(\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{y})^2}}{\sqrt{1+\overrightarrow{x}^2}\sqrt{1+\overrightarrow{y}^2}}d^2x d^2y
\end{equation}

I would like to find out if this integral converges or diverges. However, I am totally stuck due to the exponent $-(\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{y})^2$.

I tried to expand the exponent and separate out the cases in which the cross-term $\overrightarrow{x} \cdot \overrightarrow{y}$ is positive or negative, but this plan does not seem to work out easily.

Could anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: What is $(\overrightarrow{x})^{2}$?

Comment: Oh, it is just $\overrightarrow{x} \cdot \overrightarrow{x}$ where $\cdot$ is the inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll drop the arrows because I am not used to them. I'll use $x$ and $y$ to denote vectors in the plane. Change variables, taking $w= (x+y)/2$ and $z = (x-y)/2$, you are now integrating

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{e^{-4||z||^2}}{\sqrt{1+ ||w+z||^2 } \sqrt{1+ ||w-z||^2 }} $$

Now if you multiply the factors in the square roots you get:

$$ 1 + ||w+z||^2 + ||w-z||^2 + ||w+z||^2 ||w-z||^2=1 +2||w||^2 + 2 ||z||^2 + (||w||^2 +||z||^2)^2 - 4 \langle w,z\rangle^2 = 1+ 2 ||w-z||^2  + (||w||^2 + ||z||^2)^2 \leq 1 + 2 (||w||+||z||)^2 + (||w||^2 + ||z||^2)^2 $$

I want to prove divergence, so I am allowed to estimate the quantity in the square root with something bigger. You end up with having to prove the divergence of

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{e^{-4||z||^2}}{\sqrt{1+2 (||w||+||z||)^2 + (||w||^2 + ||z||^2)^2}} .$$

Since it's all radial, pass to polar coordinates and reduce to studying the behavior of
$$ \int_{0} ^{+\infty} \int_{0} ^{+ \infty} \frac{e^{-4u^2} uv}{\sqrt{1+2 (u+v)^2 + (u^2 + v^2)^2}} dudv .$$

And this does not converge (can you see why?)

Comment: Yes, due to $v$, the last integral seems logarithmically divergent. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly. If that thing converged you could integrate in every fiber along $v$ by Fubini, and thus you would need that (almost) every integral over $\{u\} \times \mathbb{R}$ converged. But it is not the case, as you said